# How to update the contents of the first response with axios based on the second response

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I wrote the following action in Nuxt.js.

```
async fetchAllCategoryPosts({ commit }) {
  await this.$axios.$get(`${process.env.apiBaseUrl}/posts/categories`).then(res => {
    for (const data of res) {
      this.$axios.$get(`${process.env.apiBaseUrl}/posts/categories/${data.category_id}`).then(posts =>{
        data['posts'] = posts
      })
    }
    console.log(res)
  })
}
```

The contents of `res` of the first request are as follows

```
[
  { 'category_id': 1 },
  { 'category_id': 4 },
  { 'category_id': 9 },
  { 'category_id': 11 }
]
```

And, based on the result, I want to send a second request and finally edit `res` as follows.

```
[
  { 'category_id': 1, 'posts': [{object}, {object} ...] },
  { 'category_id': 4 'posts': [{object}, {object} ...] },
  { 'category_id': 9 'posts': [{object}, {object} ...] },
  { 'category_id': 11 'posts': [{object}, {object} ...] }
]
```

However, with the above code, the result of `console.log (res)` has no change with the state of the first request.
How can we respond?

Comment: Check moving this line console.log(res) below  data['posts'] = posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. I could not test this due to lack of environment, but this should work. Do let me know in case of errors

```
async fetchAllCategoryPosts({ commit }) {
  this.$axios.$get(`${process.env.apiBaseUrl}/posts/categories`).then(res => {
    let newRes = await Promise.all(res.data.map(async (data) => await this.$axios
      .$get(`${process.env.apiBaseUrl}/posts/categories/${data.category_id}`)
      .then(posts => ({...data, posts}));

    console.log(newRes);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The beauty of async/await is that you can escape the "callback hell" and work with the data as if it was synchronous.

```
async fetchAllCategoryPosts({ commit }) {
  const categories = await this.$axios.$get(`${process.env.apiBaseUrl}/posts/categories`);
  const withPosts = await Promise.all(
    categories.map( async cat => ({ 
      ...cat, 
      posts: await this.$axios.get(`${process.env.apiBaseUrl}/posts/categories/${cat.category_id}`)
    })
  );
  return withPosts;
};
```

edit: I did not test this with vue/axios, but it has worked with plain es6 and substituting `fetch` for `this.$axios.get`.